# How to run Javascript Application

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please advise how to run this application

https://github.com/exam-simulator/maker-frontend

I have already cloned the application but don't know where to go from there.

Please advise. Thank you

Comment: npm run dev? npm run build? npm run start? there's a few `scripts` defined in the package, give them a go

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion it greatly helped

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look in the package.json for all the scripts you can run, for this one, try

1. Installing [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. Running `npm i`
3. Running `npm build`
4. Running `npm start`

and that should just allow it to work, although I'm not sure this app is fully functional from my end.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion worked but as you pointed out the app seems incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the `package.json` and this what I understand.

- Install `Node.js` with `NPM` in your system.
- Go inside the root of the directory, open a terminal, and execute `npm install` to install the dependencies.
- Execute `npm run build` to build the app.
- Execute `npm start --port 8080` to run the app at port `8080`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggested response. It helped alot

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you! Please consider marking it as correct so it can help other people checking this question also! :)